# Need to Autoamate a control using coded UI which is not visible in Coded UI Test Builder

Tags: c#, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to automate a Winform application in which one control is detectable as WinClient which stores the Employee Information in the form of a grid. When I can double-click on any of the rows it opens another window with employee information.

I trying identifying the Grid control with coded UI Test builder but it is recognizing as the control as winclient.

WinClient control has grid and other text box for each row to search a particular employee.
I'm able to identify text box but not the grid info.

I tried automating it with Coded UI, Autoamtion Element and White Framework, it didn't work for me.

Is there any way I can open an employee info window directly by passing the emp id? Which would run in background when the application is running.

I mean I don't want to perform UI Operation, in turn, I want to call that method directly when a click event is triggered.

I have the DLL of the client application.

I cannot paste the code or screenshot because of security issues.

Please bear with my grammar.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Coded UI is for testing the UI, it is not for calling methods in DLLs. Please provide much more detail of what you are trying to do, what you have already tried and why that did not work. Please also read [mcve] and provide enough detail that your question can be understood. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed as too broad.